# SBT error: "Runtime reference to undefined setting"

Tags: scala, sbt

I am trying to reference another `Github` project as a build dependency in `sbt` using the following code that sits in `build.sbt`:

```
lazy val dependency = RootProject(uri("..."))

// The Play project itself
lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .enablePlugins(Common, PlayScala, GatlingPlugin)
  .configs(GatlingTest)
  .settings(inConfig(GatlingTest)(Defaults.testSettings): _*)
  .dependsOn(dependency)
  .settings(
    name := """play-scala-rest-api-example""",
    scalaSource in GatlingTest := baseDirectory.value / "/gatling/simulation"
  )
```

And I get the error:

```
Runtime reference to undefined setting:
[error]
[error]   ProjectRef(uri("..."), "dependency")
```

Comment: What is the reason against publishing the artifact from the other project and using it as a dependency?

Comment: I'd have to do that with any significant update.